# first() is not adding in first line

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am trying to add new rows in df based on first rows.

```
id                        name                              value
111                   length                                46
111                   status                              completed
111                    segment                              21
555                     tp                                 0.1
555                     x                                  56
888                     point                              23.01
888                     x                                  50
888                     y                                  40
```

expected output

```
     id                        name                              value
    111                       type                                description #new row
    111                    length                                46
    111                    status                              completed
    111                   segment                               21
    555                       type                               description  #new row
    555                    tp                                   0.1
    555                     x                                    56
    888                     type                                description  #new row
    888                     point                                23.01
    888                     x                                    50
    888                     y                                    40
```

i am trying

```
new = df.groupby("id", as_index=False).first().assign(attribute='rdf:type', value='description')
df = pd.concat([new, df]).sort_values('id')
```

it only insert first row fine  but then it add on last of 555  after x and some where it add in between e.g after y.I have thousands of rows in df.can any body please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def prepend(grp):
    new_row = pd.DataFrame([[ grp.iloc[0].id, 'type', 'description' ]],
        columns=grp.columns)
    return pd.concat([new_row, grp])
```

Then apply it:

```
result = df.groupby('id').apply(prepend).droplevel(level=0)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

## Edit following the comment concerning position of new rows

For your sample data (and automatically generated index) I received the
proper result.

One reason why the order of rows can be different is that maybe some rows
in your DataFrame have negative indices.
In this case:

- the first (added row) is generated with index == *0*,
- other with "original" indices,

hence the concatenation order may be different, e.g. using some older
version of *Pandas* (I tried to set such negative indices, but even then
I still got the proper sequence of rows).

Try changing the last line in *prepend* to:

```
return pd.concat([new_row, grp], ignore_index=True)
```

i.e. add *ignore_index=True*.

In this case old index values are ignored and in each group index values
will be consecutive numbers.
In the last step (*reset_index*) they will be overwritten with the
new sequence of consecutive numbers, but at least there should be
the proper order of rows in the results returned by each application
of *prepend*.

Comment: @ Valdi_Bo some time it add at first line, some time on  last or second last .

Comment: This solution works for me...it returns the expected output you wanted. Perhaps your example data isn't representative of the data you're actually using?

Comment: I have almost same data there are thousands of rows. every id has different number of rows some has 5,7 or 9. name column values are not sorted but they all are strings

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the grouped dataframes:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for id_, df_ in df.groupby('id'):
    final_df = final_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[id_, 'rdf:type', 'description']], columns=df.columns))
    final_df = final_df.append(df_)
final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then you'll get

```
     id      name        value
0   111  rdf:type  description
1   111    length           46
2   111    status    completed
3   111   segment           21
4   555  rdf:type  description
5   555        tp          0.1
6   555         x           56
7   888  rdf:type  description
8   888     point        23.01
9   888         x           50
10  888         y           40
```

Comment: @ ignoring_gravity, it is throwing following error "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 3)"

Comment: @user19 did you copy-and-paste the code as I wrote it? Did you include the double square brackets in the dataframe constructor?

Comment: sorry i  missed the double square bracket now it is running, but same problem it is adding new row in last or second last position

Comment: So the output you're seeing is different to the one I posted?

Comment: no I want the same output which you posted.... but  I am not getting the same output

Comment: @user19 are you using the same input which you posted in your question?

Comment: data is different but format is same. i have three columns,id col only has number but type is string name col has  values which are not in any alphabetical order.I want to  insert new line at first place of every new id.